# VBA DOM Specific Node and Attribute ID

Tags: xml, vba, dom, xml-parsing, attributes

I have a large XML file that I'm trying to parse using DOM. What I'm trying to do is pull information from an attribute node if it's child contains a certain value.

For example,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
<book id="Adventure">
   <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
   <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
   <price>44.95</price>
</book>
<book id="Adventure">
   <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
   <title>Midnight Rain</title>
   <price>5.95</price>
</book>
<book id="Adventure">
   <author>Boal, John</author>
   <title>Mist</title>
   <price>15.95</price>
</book>
<book id="Mystery">
   <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
   <title>Some Mystery Book</title>
   <price>9.95</price>
</book>
</catalog>
```

So from here, let's say I want to find books written by the author "Ralls, Kim":

```
Sub mySub()

Dim mainWorkBook As Workbook
Dim XMLFile As Variant
Dim BookType As String
Dim Author As Variant
Dim athr As String
Dim n As IXMLDOMNode
Dim i As Integer

Set mainWorkBook = ActiveWorkbook
Set XMLFILE = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")

XMLFILE.Load (XCMFileName) 'Load XCM File

Set Author = XMLFILE.SelectNodes("/catalog/book/author/text()")
For i = 0 To (Author.Length - 1)
    athr= Author(i).NodeValue 
    If athr = "Ralls, Kim" Then
        mainWorkBook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & i + 3).Value = athr
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Now what if I wanted to display the book type (ie "Adventure/Mystery") in the next column, how would I do that? I'm trying to think backwards but I don't know how to even begin this.

I understand that I can use XPath and IXMLDOMNode to get the attribute id, but I simply don't know how to actually go about doing this since it seems backwards.

Thanks for any tips and pointers - I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go "up" a couple of steps to get to the parent "book" element and read the `id` attribute from there:

```
Sub mySub()

Dim mainWorkBook As Workbook
Dim XMLFile As Variant
Dim BookType As String
Dim Author As Variant
Dim athr As String
Dim n As IXMLDOMNode
Dim i As Long, x As Long

    Set mainWorkBook = ActiveWorkbook
    Set XMLFile = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")

    XMLFILE.Load (XCMFileName) 'Load XCM File

    x = 3

    Set Author = XMLFile.SelectNodes("/catalog/book/author/text()")
    For i = 0 To (Author.Length - 1)
        athr = Author(i).NodeValue
        If athr = "Ralls, Kim" Then
            With mainWorkBook.Sheets("Sheet1")
            .Range("C" & x).Value = athr
            .Range("D" & x).Value = _
                Author(i).ParentNode.ParentNode.getAttribute("id")
            End With
            x = x + 1
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey Tim, thanks for your response and help. Just one quick question if you don't mind: if I wanted to store the BookType values into an array, would I just define a new array `Dim myStr() As String` and then put `myStr() = Author(i).ParentNode.ParentNode.getAttribute("id")` inside the With statement? This way I can print these values outside of the loop at a later time if needed.

Comment: You could only assign the values one by one and you'd need to resize the array as you add each item, but yes you can do that.